# How to execute proof by cases which customized by ourself

Tags: isabelle

I'd like to prove a lemma by cases. Assume that I have two variables r1 and r2, r2 is free variable, and r1 r2 belongs to same datatypes. Thus there is an idea that I want to prove the lemma by cases of r1 = r2 and r1 != r2. I know there exists a struct of proof(cases) in isabelle, but how to proof by the cases r2 of ...

```
 ∀q∈reg2q r1 v. sem_reg q v = {w. LTS_is_reachable (fst (trans2LTS r1 v)) (snd (trans2LTS r1 v)) q w ε} ⟹
    q ∈ reg2q r1 v ⟹
    LTS_is_reachable (fst (trans2LTS r1 v) ∪ fst (trans2LTS r2 v)) (insert (Alter r1 r2, r1) (insert (Alter r1 r2, r2) (snd (trans2LTS r1 v) ∪ snd (trans2LTS r2 v)))) q x ε ⟹
    LTS_is_reachable (fst (trans2LTS r1 v)) (snd (trans2LTS r1 v)) q x ε
```

Any help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your example in such a way that one understands what you're trying to prove? (Ideally, you would minimize the example to be self-contained, so one can copy it into Isabelle.) Generally, you can just write `proof (cases ‹r1 = r2›)` and this will create the cases `True` and `False` for the possible boolean values of `‹r1 = r2›`.

Comment: The method proof (cases ‹r1 = r2›) is exactly right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: May I ask you about other proof methods, I am a new one in Isabelle. In the tutorial, it doesn't mention it.